# wso2 developer version 4.5

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

currently I am trying to setup WSO2 identity server in my local environment. I tried with developer version of WSO2 4.5 . but getting build errors . I have JDK and Apache Maven ready in my machine. Do I require anything other than these. Or somebody can provide the link where I can download the exact build able version with source files.

Comment: What do you mean by developer version?

Comment: Hi i mean i tried to download SVN 4.1.0 version . not able to build it and i am not getting any source files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such developer version. You can download binary distribution product from here [1]. Latest version is 4.5.0. If you want to download the source. you need to SVN CO all carbon platform.  Because  Identity server is an one product of Carbon platform. Identity server consists of Carbon kernel and some components in the carbon platform. Please check this [2] to see, how you can build the carbon platform

[1] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/
[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Building+from+Source

Comment: Thanks a lot Asela. I downloaded the same . I tried same steps but i am getting build errors when building kernel 4.2.0 . please see following error .. Error injecting: org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)

Comment: What is the maven version that you are using?  Could you try with maven 3.0.X?  It seems to be that there is some issue with maven 3.1.X. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

Comment: Basically you can not build identity server source using maven 3.1.X You must use maven 3.0.X (i have used maven 3.0.4) and it is working fine... Please try to move to maven 3.0.X and see whether you are getting this error?

Comment: Thanks Asela all working fine now. I am able to build the following links succesffully  
1. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/branches/4.2.0/
2. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0
3. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/. Now my question is how can i get source files for the IS from this. please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically WSO2 Identity Server is only one product in Carbon platform. Source code of the whole platform can be found here [1].You have built all the source of the platform which is correct. Because there are dependencies for each other. Carbon platform consists of many features (set of OSGI component). As an example,  XACML (we said it as "entitlement" ) is an one feature of WSO2 Carbon platform and it is shipped with WSO2 Identity Server. Like that there are several feature such as SSO, OAuth, WS-Trust and many more... that are shipped with Identity Server. Therefore; Say, if you are only interesting in XACML feature,  you can look in to the XACML feature's source code. XACML feature is a set of four OSGI components as follows...

org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement [2]  ->  This is the core component.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui [3] --> This contains the management console UI that can be seen once you login to the server. 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.common [4] --> This contains some common functions of both core and UI
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub [5] --> This contains auto generated stub class. This helps UI component to call the backend services.

Like that,  you can find the source of the feature that you are interested. We can not find the WSO2 Identity Sever's product source from one place.  However most of the source are under  /platform/components/identity

Also say that you want to create a product with only XACML features, you can do it also. Here you want to only install XACML feature to Carbon core product. Same as  WSO2 Identity Server has been built by installing several features to Carbon core product.

[1] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/
[2] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement/4.2.0/
[3] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui/4.2.0/
[4] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.common/4.2.0/
[5] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub/4.2.0/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source of components for IS at [1].

[1] - https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/